# Android Action bar

Tags: android-actionbar, android, android-support-library, android-actionbar-compat

I am trying to demo the Android Action Bar and have created an app to try it with. I have installed and linked the library to the project ( I think properly ), and have to the best of my knowledge set it up correctly.  The problem though, is that the MainActivity fails to load any of the main resource files.

MainActivity layout:

```
  Create field 'activity_main' in type 'layout'
```

Menu xml file:

```
Create field 'menu' in type 'R'
```

The theme in the Manifest:

```
No resource found that matches the given name ( at 'theme' with a value
'@style/Theme_appCompat_Light_DarkActionBar')
```

The main layout and the menu xml both exist, but I admit i don't know where the theme file is to confirm that it exists, though I don't think that is the issue.

I have taken a [screenshot](http://puu.sh/4IEgJ.png/) that shows the configuration of my projects

The test application and the appcompat folders exist in the same place in the file system, and the build path and library entries all look correct. I can attach screens of those configurations as well if need be.

I feel that this is some kind of configuration error, but i am very new to android development and don't have enough information about the project structure to see where I need to make a change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an error in your AndroidManifest.xml. Eclipse won't generate the R ( references file) file until there are no errors in your xml files.

You'll also need the android-support-v13.jar library as that would have some themes in there as well.

If that doesn't work for the theme in the Manifest, you'll need an appropriate themes.xml in your values folder that has the theme name you're looking for. Here's an example:

```
<!-- 
    the theme applied to the application or activity 
-->    
<style name="CustomLightTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">

</style>
```